# Difference between UI Component and Service Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, developer

Below piece of text is mentioned in official documentation of LWC Salesforce Developer guide.

**Additional JavaScript Files**

In addition to the JavaScript file that creates the HTML element, a component’s folder can contain other JavaScript files.*"Use these JavaScript files to structure code in UI components, and share code from service components"*

My Question:
I was just reading about Additional Javascript files topic and I came across the second line from above paragraph. I have italicized and included in double quotes. I didn't understand the terms UI component and service components. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2):

A UI component has an `.html` template file. A service component does not.

In other words, a file listing for the two components might look like:

```
+ uiComponent
  + uiComponent.html
  + uiComponent.js
  + uiComponent.js-meta.xml
+ serviceComponent
  + serviceComponent.js
  + serviceComponent.js-meta.xml
```

Note that you cannot include a service component in a template, because it has nothing to render. Given the files above, for example, this code is invalid:

```
<template>
  <c-service-component></c-service-component>
</template>
```

As a simple example, let's say you had a component called `utils`, and a function called `add`, to add numbers together:

```
export function add(...values) {
  return values.reduce((sum,value)=>sum+value,0);
}
```

You can then use that in another component:

```
import { add } from 'c/utils';
console.log(add(1,2,3,4,5)); // Logs 15
```

You can use this to share JavaScript between many components without using the [`lightning-platform-resource-loader`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader) and static resources. You can even have multiple JavaScript files in single service component to keep your code organized.